# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) error with table view

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBOutlet weak var table_List: UITableView!

var todoList:[String] = ["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "ToDo List"
    let addButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addToDo))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
}

func addToDo(){
    let name:String = "Row \(todoList.count+1)"
    todoList.insert(name, at: 0)
    let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    table_List.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

I'm receiving the error stated in the title and have no idea why. Currently trying to create a custom but dynamic toDo list (For learning purposes only really) but have ran in to this lil stump.

table_List.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

^^ That is where the error is...

Appreciate all the help I receive.

Comment: Probably `table_List` is not properly connected and therefore `nil`

Comment: That actually worked! Thank you mate. Now how do I mark your comment as the answer lmfao